# Why does value-of leave off the attributes?

Tags: xslt

If I have this xml

**beans.xml**

```xml
<soup type="beans">
    <can>dented</can>
</soup>
```

and I do this in xslt

```xml
<xsl:variable name="bean-soup" select="document('beans.xml')/soup"/>
<xsl:variable name="no-soup-for-you">
    <xsl:value-of select="$bean-soup"/>
</xsl:variable>
beans: <xsl:value-of select="$bean-soup/@type"/>
no beans: <xsl:value-of select="$no-soup-for-you/@type"/>
```

I have a work-around, so I was able to get my `beans` another way.

Why is the attribute missing in the second variable, when it's there in the first variable? Please ELI5 (i.e., without resorting to set theory or opaque W3C notations) why the attributes would be stripped out of a reference to a variable? It is astonishing (and that's bad; [you're not supposed to astonish other developers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)).

Comment: Regarding `xsl:copy-of`, please provide a [mcve] showing how it leaves off the attributes. Regarding, `xsl:value-of` ...  uhm, have you read the specification of what it does? It is far from being "opaque". In a nutshell, it creates a *text node* with the [string-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-String-Functions) of the  selected node/s. A text node has no attributes.

Comment: `<soup @type="beans">` is syntactically wrong, it must be `<soup type="beans">`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I removed `copy-of` from my question. The thrust of the question is about `value-of`. I just mentioned `copy-of` as an aside, and it's not worth the distraction.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, yeah, typo. My app really isn't about beans so I was typing freehand.

Comment: Well, then you should have your answer. Your `$no-soup-for-you` variable contains the string "dented", surrounded (possibly) by some white space. That's what `xsl:value-of` does.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, regarding value-of, ok so the first variable works because it was from a `select`. So, how would I create a variable that gets either the bean soup or the lentil soup based on a `choose` and preserves the type attribute?

Comment: Sorry, you lost me at this point. Perhaps you should edit your question and post the [real problem](https://xyproblem.info/) you are struggling with. Or start a new one.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Sorry. I'll rephrase my followup. In the xsl:variable `no-soup-for-you`, say you have a `choose` that needs to return one element or another depending on the `when` conditions. Which xslt mechanism would you use to get a complete reference (as `select` seems to do) to the element you chose (which includes the attributes and all the children, etc.)?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, another way to say it is this: When I have some logic that prevents me from simply using the `select` attribute of `xsl:variable`, which forces me to use the "inside" of the `xsl:variable`, how do I replicate the functionality of `select`?

Comment: I am afraid this is not going anywhere. Please edit your question and provide a [mcve]. Also state which version of XSLT we are talking about.

Comment: P.S. If I am guessing (!) correctly, you are asking the same question as the one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57802213/setting-a-variable-conditionally-with-no-cut-of-ancestor-axis. Note that this is about XSLT 1.0; it can be much simpler in XSLT 2.0 or higher.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, you guessed correctly. The answer there is what I needed in this case. I had no idea you could put unrelated boolean expressions in the bracket after an element name (which result in true or false) and have those feed into an "or" (union) statement. Anyway, it is *astonishing* that xsl:variable creates a result tree fragment instead of a nodeset. And it's pathetic/deplorable/pickanadjective that there isn't a `<xsl:reference-to select="whatever"/>` operation to compliment `xsl:value-of` and `xsl:copy-of` which simply returns a nodeset which you can use in `xsl:variable` body.

Comment: Well, the "astonishing" (and all your other adjectives) fault has been corrected in XSLT 2.0 (and even in XSLT 1.1, if your processor happens to support it). That happened more than 20 years ago, so it's hardly worth complaining about it now.